# cannot connect to git repository at remote server on netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, remote-server

I created a git repo at remote server.
I want to acces that repo via netbeans.
I followed

```
team->git->clone
```

this is the screenshot of error

this is the git repo position.

http://mobimage.co/index.php?i=b93e28

this is repo adress:
http://188.226.161.12/repo.git/

Answer (score 9):

If you want to connect git on `https` you must add some config data in `C:Users\username\.gitconfig`

```
sslVerify = false[http]
```

By command line

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the remote server to support http?

If not simply create ssh keys `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email"` and upload the private key to your remote server.

Now you will be able to clone it via ssh.

If you dont want to add ssh keys use the `https://` prototocol and it will promot you for tpassword.

Comment: Hello i tried to do what you said and this problem occurred. http://mobimage.co/index.php?i=37338f   But i am assure that i send the right ssh key at server.